# ResetPasswordAsync raise an error

Tags: asp.net, identity

Recently I download the visual studuio 2015 RC and I want to implement the reset password in my app. I wrote some line for do this:

```
ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
ApplicationUser _user = context.Users.First(u => u.UserName == UserName);
var resetResult = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(_user, ResetToken, NewPassword);
```

and I create a token in the previos function as follow :

```
ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
ApplicationUser _user = context.Users.First(u => u.UserName == UserName);
var ResetToken = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(_user);
```

But an error raised on the line of ResetPasswordAsync :

**The instance of entity type 'IX.InfoBay.Framework.ApplicationUser' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked. For new entities consider using an IIdentityGenerator to generate unique key values.**

The connection and other settings are ok because I can do registering and updating the users.

Answer (score 0):

The error message pretty much tells you what is the problem: you cannot track the `IX.InfoBay.Framework.ApplicationUser` object, since it is already being tracked.

You are executing this line twice:

```
ApplicationUser _user = context.Users.First(u => u.UserName == UserName);
```

Why don't you just use the `_user` object again?

Comment: I must to pass it to reset password function . I have to initiate an ApplicationUser object. can I do any other function for doing this function ?

Comment: Why don't you pass it to the reset password function without initiating it again? Remember: initiating again means another request to the database server.